# Template is missing error when I destroy a comment using Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

All,

The destroy method in my comments controller is not finding the corresponding view when I delete a comment.  I double checked my destroy.js.erb file and it looks correct.  I double checked the comments controller as well and I couldn't find anything. In my _comment.html.erb file I have set the remote to true so it should find the corresponding app view to pick up. Can anyone offer any guidance?

**Error message**

```
Missing template comments/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}.
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
      class CommentsController < ApplicationController
       def create
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.new(params.require(:comment).permit(:body))
       @comment.user = current_user
       authorize @comment

         if @comment.save #save the code down in the database
        flash[:notice] = "Your comment was saved!"
        else
           flash[:error] = "Your comment failed to save."
        end

       redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]
     end

     def destroy
       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
       @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

       authorize @comment
          if @comment.destroy
             flash[:notice] = "Comment was removed."
         else
             flash[:error] = "Comment couldn't be deleted. Try again."
         end
         #redirect_to [@post.topic, @post]

          respond_to do |format| #tell controller to responde via Ajax
          format.html #return response type in html
          format.js #return response type in js
         end
      end
   end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

```
   <% if @comment.destroyed? %>
   $('#comment-' +<%= @comment.id %>).hide();
   $('.js-comments-count').html("<%= pluralize(@comment.user.comments.count, 'comment') %>");
   <% else %>
   $('#comment-' +<%= @comment.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] %>   </div");
   <% end %>
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
 <div class="media">
  <%= content_tag :div, class: 'media', id: "comment-#{comment.id}" do   %>
  <%= link_to '#', class: 'pull-left' do %>
  <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url, class: "media-object")       if comment.user.avatar? %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
    <div class="media-body">
     <small>
      <%= comment.user.name %> commented <%=     time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
  <% if policy(comment).destroy? %>
    | <%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete,    remote: true %>
  <% end %>
    </small>
   <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: is your destroy.js.erb located in the following folder? views/comments/

Comment: yes its located under views/comments.

Comment: what is the url you call to get there? does it end in .js?

Comment: That's likely your problem then :) If your not ending it in .js AND you don't have that format set as default in your routes then you will never make it to destroy.js.erb file. so if this is your path /some-path.js it will use that file and if you don't specifiy it will try and find a file called destroy.html.erb which im assuming you don't have since you didn't include it in your question.

Comment: I don't believe that is it.  If I enable the delete link in the view to use Ajax by doing "remote: true".  That should call the destroy method from the comment controller that should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destroy.js.erb file was not able to find the comment.id within the div class.  To fix the issue I removed the div class portion and the destory.js.erb was able to find the comment.id and my destroy.js.erb deleted the comment successfully with no error.

```
 <%= content_tag :div, class: 'media', id: "comment-#{comment.id}" do    %>
<%= link_to '#' do %>
  <%= image_tag(comment.user.avatar.small.url) if comment.user.avatar? %>
  <% end %>


<small>
  <%= comment.user.name %> commented <%=    time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago
  <% if policy(comment).destroy? %>
    | <%= link_to "Delete", [comment.post, comment], method: :delete,     remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</small>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
```